# How to use chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener parameter as global variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Im trying to get chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener parameter out of function. But it works just inside method.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
        alert(response); // its ok!
});
```

But when Im trying to declare it as external variable, it do not work.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
        response = response;
});

alert(response); // Underfined;(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The core of the problem is **Asynchronous vs synchronous** methods

In the [chrome-extension tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync), it has:

> Most methods in the chrome.* APIs are asynchronous: they return immediately, without waiting for the operation to finish. If you need to know the outcome of that operation, then you pass a callback function into the method. That callback is executed later (potentially much later), sometime after the method returns.

#### About this problem, if you write the code like this:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
        response = response;
});

alert(response);
```

The `chrome.runtime...` and the `alert(...)` will be executed at the same time, the `alert` function cannot get the parameter `response` because the  `chrome.runtime...` hasn't accomplished execution, and you get *undefined* result. You should write your code in the callback function like you do in the first code block.

#### You may get more inspiration from the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync-example) by the tutorial.

So in this case, I think your problem is more about **execution method** than **function scope**. Hope this helps.